# USB Serial support registered for ch341-uart in dmesg but /dev/ttyUSB0 does'nt show up in Debian12 on OrangePI Zero 3

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, debian

I need to connect a Tlora32 device (ESP32 based) on USB serial port but no /dev/ttyUSB0 shows up despite the usb serial driver is loaded as seen in dmesg:

```
[    7.042635] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[    7.042687] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[    7.095432] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for ch341-uart
```

and also lsusb shows:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter
```

I tried also to create /dev/ttyUSB0 with mknod and set a rule 99-usb-serial.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7523", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB0"
```

in /etc/udev/rules.d/ and eventually set service udev restart to let the driver being associated to ttyUSB0 but after this I got in dmesg:

```
[    7.095526] ch341 4-1:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected 
[    7.106783] usb 4-1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0 
[    8.701029] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
```

I don't understand the reason why ch341-uart disconnects, I read somewhere about britty might be causing this but britty is not there in my Debian config at all.

Sorry for me to have read britty instead of brltty.. Actually problem solved just removing brltty that was configured in my Debian installation. Problem solved!